# Multisite with Different URLs on Local Server

Tags: multisite

Maybe this has been answered before, but when I read through the other answers it didn't seem to address my issue. I could be totally wrong though.

I have WordPress Multisite loaded on a local server with sub-domains enabled. My primary domain is linuxweb1.powerstonepm.com. All of my sites are example.linuxweb1.powerstonepm.com.

The first site I tried to change the URL name from harbourvista.linuxweb1.powerstonepm.com to harbourvista.powerstonepm.com and pointed the dns to the changed URL. I ran Search and Replace to change all URLs. When I tried to login, it redirected me to the primary domain instead of the subdomain. When I was finally able to login, it wouldn't let me into the dashboard.

My wp-config is setup as:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'linuxweb1.powerstonepm.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );
```

Does it have anything to do with the, "linuxweb1" in the primary domain and when I changed the subdomain to harbourvista.powerstonepm.com I removed it?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here, which might be helpful in resolving your problem. Domain names for sub-sites in multisites are contained in the site's Settings. The answer tells you how to get there, and the htaccess commands which may help.

[Trying to migrate a Wordpress Multisite with Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313045/trying-to-migrate-a-wordpress-multisite-with-domain-mapping/314443#314443)